# file_exists() return FALSE

Tags: php, file-permissions, file-exists

I can't access a file in my server which has the permission of `rw-r--r--`, The `file_exists()` functions always return `FALSE` What to change for the access?

Comment: change permission with `chmod 755 /path/to/file.txt`

Comment: Is it possible to do with PHP somehow? My script run also in the same server.

Comment: 1. it's `file_exists()` 2. it should return true actually, for permissions check there's `is_readable`, so check your filepath, also output the current `dirname(__FILE__)` and see if the path is correct relatively to your file

Comment: and check with !is_dir also, if file name is absent in case

Comment: Make sure that path you are checking is correct.

Comment: @Alex, Let me try these things. And the function name was typo mistake.

Comment: all directories in the path should be executable by the user

Answer (score 0):

The function is actually `file_exists(path)` not file_exist() if talking about php, and file_exists() needs to use a file path on the drive and not a URL.

So you should do something like:

```
$file = '/var/www/html/scripts/asset/some_file.png';
if(file_exists($file))
{
    //Will enter here if the file actually exists in that path
}
```

Comment: It was a typo mistake, I use the correct function name for sure.